# Nginx subfolder as location

Tags: nginx

My nginx.conf contains this:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     myserver.com X.X.X.X;
    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_buffering     off;
        proxy_connect_timeout 43200000;
        proxy_send_timeout    43200000;
        proxy_read_timeout    43200000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    }

    location /api/socket {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/api/socket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    location /newapp {
        #Should this be empty?
    }

}
```

As you can see, both / and /api/socket point to a proxy. Both of them work. 
Originally this line didn't exist:

```
root /var/www/html;
```

I added it. I also added the "location /newapp". What I want is to go to the index file under the folder /var/www/html when I type

myserver.com/newapp

However, I get a 404. Am I missing something in the config file?

Comment: I still get 404. Interesting thing in error.log for nginx. This is printed: /var/www/html/newapp failed (2: No such file or directory)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like the URI `/newapp` (or `/newapp/index.html`) to find the file `/var/www/html/index.html`, you will need to use the `alias` directive and not the `root` directive.

For example:

```
location /newapp {
    alias /var/www/html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the folder /newapp inside /var/www/html solves the issue. But I am not sure if this is the way to go. However, it worked then.